# Big query alter table add column after a specific column in 2022

Tags: python, google-bigquery

It's Not Working:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name ADD COLUMN Marketing STRING AFTER COLUMN Detail STRING
```

OUTPUT:

> Syntax error: Expected end of input but got identifier "AFTER" at
> [4:82]

Answer (score 0):

`AFTER` is not supported in creating DDL Statement as per this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-definition-language#alter_table_add_column_statement). This statement works:

```sql
ALTER TABLE `<table_name>` ADD COLUMN Marketing STRING
```

Output:

[image]

You can just query the columns next to each other to achieve desired output.

Comment: Yes its work but i want the insert column after detail and before marketing @Anjela B

Comment: You can just add column but not dictate the placement when altering the table. You can just query them according to your desired placement. Ex. `SELECT detail, new_column, marketing FROM your_table`after adding a column.